# While True in Python - I am always getting an error message

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey so I'm complete new to programming and python and can't figure out what I did wrong in my first programm. I tried googling it but every other solution I found and tried didn't work I always get the same error message. Could maybe someone tell me what I did wrong? :)

I want that I am able to multiply until I put no into the last input.

```
welcome = "Welcome to Multiplyer!!!"
print(welcome)
name = input("Hello, please input your name: ")
print("Hello " + name + ", thank you for using Multiplyer")

while True:
print("Select two numbers")

num1 = int(input("Number 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Number 2: "))


print(num1 * num2)

 n = raw_input("Wanna multiply again? ")
    if n.strip() == 'no':
        break
```

Comment: *What error message.*

Comment: IndentantionError: expected an indented block

Comment: In loops (where line ends with a colon`:`), such as `while True:` the following block of code needs to be indented (usually by 4 spaces), as you have done in the last `if` clause

Comment: glad to hear it, very welcome @mercury33

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentation is a part of the language, so the content of the while loop should be indented:

```
welcome = "Welcome to Multiplyer!!!"
print(welcome)
name = input("Hello, please input your name: ")
print("Hello " + name + ", thank you for using Multiplyer")

while True:
    print("Select two numbers")

    num1 = int(input("Number 1: "))
    num2 = int(input("Number 2: "))


    print(num1 * num2)

    n = input("Wanna multiply again? ")
    if n.strip() == 'no':
        break
```

Comment: Wow thanks it worked!
Didn't know about the indentation. I feel so stupid now! Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
welcome = "Welcome to Multiplyer!!!"
print(welcome)
name = input("Hello, please input your name: ")
print("Hello " + name + ", thank you for using Multiplyer")

while True:
    print("Select two numbers")

    num1 = int(input("Number 1: "))
    num2 = int(input("Number 2: "))


    print(num1 * num2)

    n = raw_input("Wanna multiply again? ")
    if n.strip() == 'no':
        break
```